# How to avoid "Attempted relative import with no known parent package" with this simple package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Inside `packagetest/`, I have these four files:

- `__init__.py`:

  ```
  class TestError(Exception):
      pass
  ```
- `__main__.py`:

  ```
  from . import TestError
  from .abc import defgh
  from .ijk.lmn import opq
  ```
- `abc/__init__.py`:

  ```
  def defgh():
      pass
  ```
- `ijk/lmn.py`:

  ```
  def opq():
      pass
  ```

When running `__main__.py`, I get this error:

> File "D:\packagetest_*main*_.py", line 1, in 
> from . import TestError
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

**Why does `from . import TestError` generate an error here?**

**How to solve this problem here and modify the code as little as possible?**

I've already read [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) but I don't see how to modify my code here to make it work.

Comment: A package is to be imported. In the Python console outside the parent folder `packagetest` do an `import packagetest`. If you arbitrarily run (directly) scripts from inside your package, you will almost always get import errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution seems to move everything in a parent directory `parent/` :

```
parent/
  |- test.py
  |- packagetest/
       |- __init__.py
       |- __main__.py
       |- abc/
           |- __init__.py
       |- ijk/
           |- lmn.py
```

Then import the package inside `parent/test.py`:

```
import packagetest
```

and then it works.